# Is the Psy.D. degree (US) equivalent to the "Licenciado en Psicologia" degree?

Tags: united-states, degree, international, translations, psychology

I am not sure about this. In some scenarios, seems like a "Licenciatura/Licenciado" degree is equivalent to a Bachelor's Degree, or sometimes to a Master's Degree.

Nevertheless, in some cases "Licenciatura/Licenciado" seems to correspond to a Doctoral Degree. Examples:

- Pharm.D.="Licenciado en Farmacia" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Pharmacy#Spain)
- MVD/DVM="Licenciatura en Médico Veterinario" (http://www.vets-net.com/other/GlobalVetSchools.pdf)

The equivalence between a Doctoral Degree and "Licenciatura/Licenciado" seems to be particularly the case when the later "allows to practice ***the profession***".

A closely related question would be: what is the equivalent degree of PsyD in the Spanish-speaking countries?

Comment: @TommiBrander Why Spanish-speaking countries are equivalent to Europe? I thought there are a lot countries in Latin-America are Spanish speaking.

Comment: I've edited that; switched "europe" tag for "translations". Yet, "europe" might still be appropriate.

Comment: It's not unheard of for functionally equivalent degrees to officially be at different levels in different countries. For example, a US MD is a postgraduate qualification titled "doctor", while the UK equivalent is officially a bachelor's degree (or, rather, two bachelors' degrees earned concurrently: MB BS).

Comment: I can not be 100% certain here but to my understanding the 'Doctor' degree (as in a PhD) is always post-graduate. The licenciado degree is a graduate degree and can therefore never be equivalent. I think that what is the cause of the issue described in the OP is a translation issue (where a Licenciado en Farmacia is translated as a Doctor of Pharmacy, while Pharmacist may be a better translation).